# Understanding 「 退屈だな学校ってところも」

Tags: translation

In the second episode of *Death Note*, a 死神 says about a human school:

> 退屈だな学校ってところも

1. 退屈だ is I assume modifying 学校. So why isn't だ in its attributive form, as in 退屈なな学校 (I assume the other な is the emphasizing particle that indicates the speaker is "speaking to himself")?
2. The sentence ends abrubtly. Since it doesn't end with a verb, I assume it's being colloquially dropped. What verb could it be?
3. Is the って here short for という (being used as like a "dictionary definition"; e.g. "the so called school")?

My attempted translation would be something like

> Even this place (a so called "boring school")...(some verb)

I'd be tempted to make the verb 退屈だ but it's already at the beginning of the sentence:

> 学校ってところも退屈だな
>
> Even this place (the so-called "school") is boring!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a phrase boundary after 'na', thus: 退屈だな、学校ってところも. This is an example of right-dislocation---the plain sentence would be 学校ってところも退屈だな, and the topic, 学校ってところも, has been shifted to the right, after the verb/predicate. The effect is to give prominence to the predicate, taikutsu da na.